# Spring formatter and freemarker

Tags: spring, freemarker, formatter

I have own Formatter, but I have problem with display in **Freemarker**.

I must use **jsptaglibs**:
 `<#assign form=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"]/>`.

This works:

```
<@form.select path="train.type">
    <@form.options item="trianType" />
</@form.select>
```

This does not:

```
<@spring.formSingleSelect "train.type", trainType, "" />
```

**Why the second option does not work?** How can I make the second option work?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem myself recently. If you take a look at the spring.ftl file, you'll notice that all form handling is done by converting object values to string by the means of Freemarker itself. 
Unfortunately that means that no custom formatters or editors will work and you are stuck with JSP tags.
Is there a reason why tags don't work for you?

P.S> You have "tr**ia**nType" in your first example and "tr**ai**nType" in the second. I doubt this will change anything though :)